# Definitions of two constructors with the same signature do not clash when one is templated

Tags: c++

The following code compiles with C++14/17/20, with both GCC and Clang, even though the two constructors have the same signature for the given instantiation in `main`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <typename... OpsT>
struct compose_op {
  const std::tuple<OpsT...> ops;

  template <typename TupleT = std::tuple<OpsT...>>
  constexpr compose_op()
  {
      std::cout << "constructor 0" << std::endl;
  }
  constexpr explicit compose_op(OpsT... ops) : ops{ops...} {
      std::cout << "constructor 1" << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
    compose_op<> op{};
}
```

The second constructor is used, but if I comment it out, then the first constructor is used.

What I would like to understand is:

- Why is this not considered ambiguous, but if I make both constructors templated or neither templated, then it becomes ambiguous?
- How does C++ choose between the two constructors in this case, when both match?

Comment: It's not considered ambiguous when the standard overload resolution procedure (already linked in an answer) gives an unambiguous result. It's considered ambiguous when overload resolution fails to give a result. The choice is made by standard overload resolution (specifically the "best viable function" step).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution):

> Best viable function
>
> [... 1 through 3 do not apply, they are about implicit conversions ... ]
>
> 4. or, if not that, F1 is a non-template function while F2 is a template specialization

In simple terms: The non-template constructor wins over the template constructor.